# Trouble upgrading IEndpointRouteBuilder method from .Net6 to .Net8

Tags: c#, routes, minimal-apis, .net-8.0

The following method defines my endpoints and worked fine in .Net 6. I am upgrading this app now to .Net 8 before I get to far along since that will be standard in a few months.

```
public static void DefineEndpoints(IEndpointRouteBuilder app)
{
        
    app.MapPost(BaseRoute, CreateNoteAsync)
        .WithName("CreateNote")
        .Accepts<Note>(ContentType)
        .Produces<Note>(201).Produces<IEnumerable<ValidationFailure>>(400)
        .WithTags(Tag);

    app.MapGet(BaseRoute, GetAllNotesAsync)
        .WithName("GetNotes")
        .Produces<IEnumerable<Note>>(200)
        .WithTags(Tag);

    app.MapGet($"{BaseRoute}/{{symbol}}", GetNotesByTickerAsync)
        .WithName("GetNotesForSymbol")
        .Produces<IEnumerable<Note>>(200)
        .WithTags(Tag);
    app.MapGet($"{BaseRoute}/{{symbol}}/{{date}}", GetNotesForSymbolOnDateAsync)
        .WithName("GetNotesForSymbolByDate")
        .Produces<IEnumerable<Note>>(200)
        .WithTags(Tag);

    app.MapPut($"{BaseRoute}/{{symbol}}/{{date}}", UpdateNoteAsync)
        .WithName("UpdateNote")
        .Accepts<Note>(ContentType)
        .Produces<Note>(200).Produces<IEnumerable<ValidationFailure>>(400)
        .WithTags(Tag);

    app.MapDelete($"{BaseRoute}/{{symbol}}/{{date}}", DeleteNoteAsync)
        .WithName("DeleteNote")
        .Produces(204).Produces(404)
        .WithTags(Tag);
    // rest removed for brevity
}
```

The error produced is

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS1929  'IEndpointConventionBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Accepts' and the best extension method overload 'OpenApiRouteHandlerBuilderExtensions.Accepts(RouteHandlerBuilder, string, params string[])' requires a receiver of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouteHandlerBuilder'   BATLWebApp.Net8.Api C:\Users\Trader\source\repos\BATLWebApp.Net8\BATLWebApp.Net8.Api\Endpoints\NoteEndpoints.cs 19  Active

I get the same error for the .Produces method as well.

I can see it is telling me that I need to be using the RouteHandlerBuilder but from what I see in the .Net 8 docs, the RouteHandlerBuilder takes an IEnumerable

> RouteHandlerBuilder(IEnumerable)

and the OpenApiRouteHandlerBuilderExtensions class needs that builder.

I'm not that versed in using minimal api's and am having trouble refactoring this to work in .Net 8 and am equally unsure the error is pushing me in the right direction. Any api routing experts familiar with .Net 8 methods please help.

UPDATE:
Here is a sample of the methods called. They all are async Task.

```
private static async Task<IResult> CreateNoteAsync(Note note, TableServiceManager tableServiceManager, IValidator<Note> validator)
{
    var validationResult = await validator.ValidateAsync(note);
    if (!validationResult.IsValid)
    {
        return Results.BadRequest(validationResult.Errors);
    }
    var equityNote = MapNoteToEquityNoteEntity(note);

    try
    {
        var created = await tableServiceManager.AddEquityNoteAsync(equityNote);
        Results.Created($"/{BaseRoute}/{note.Ticker}", note);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var errorMessage = $"Error creating note for {note.Ticker} on {note.NoteDate} due to {ex.Message}";
        Log.Error(ex, errorMessage);
        return Results.BadRequest(errorMessage);
    }
    return Results.BadRequest();
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `CreateNoteAsync`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `EndpointRouteBuilderExtensions` has two methods `MapGet` :

```cs
public static class EndpointRouteBuilderExtensions
{
    public static RouteHandlerBuilder MapGet(
        this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints,
        [StringSyntax("Route")] string pattern,
        Delegate handler)
    { ... }

    public static IEndpointConventionBuilder MapGet(
        this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints,
        [StringSyntax("Route")] string pattern,
        RequestDelegate requestDelegate)
    { ... }
}
```

I suspect the method than handle the request (`CreateNoteAsync`, `GetAllNotesAsync`, ... ) is of type `RequestDelegate`, then the compiler choose the `MapGet` method that return `IEndpointConventionBuilder` that hasn't `Accept` method.

You can add explicit cast to force the compiler to choose the correct method `MapGet`:

```cs
app.MapPost(BaseRoute, (Delegate)CreateNoteAsync)
    .WithName("CreateNote")
    .Accepts<Note>(ContentType)
    .Produces<Note>(201).Produces<IEnumerable<ValidationFailure>>(400)
    .WithTags(Tag);
```